# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType', trying to use my webcam for object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

```
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
     with detection_graph.as_default():
       with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
         while True:

          # Read frame from camera
           ret, image_np = cap.read()
           # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
          image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
          # Extract image tensor
          image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
         # Extract detection boxes
          boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
          # Extract detection scores
          scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
          # Extract detection classes
          classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
          # Extract number of detectionsd
          num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(
            'num_detections:0')
        # Actual detection.
        (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
            [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
            feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
        # Visualization of the results of a detection.
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np,
            np.squeeze(boxes),
            np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
            np.squeeze(scores),
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            line_thickness=8)

        # Display output
        cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (800, 600)))

        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

## So there is i am trying to use my webcam for real time object detection but there is an error occuring on this cell

## int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: what is in `classes`?  I bet it isn't what you think it is...

Comment: i am doing something wrong?

Comment: you are converting whatever is in `classes` to integer, but the error message you are getting is saying that whatever is in `classes` is `None` which can't be converted to an integer.

Comment: well, i am using an pre-trained model coco v2 and it has 90 classes, and i am following a video from the youtube

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: print out `classes right before the error occurs. Figure out what is `None` and why and how to fix it.

Comment: Tensor("detection_classes:0", shape=(?, 100), dtype=float32)

Comment: now this shape attribute have none value

Answer (score 0):

I see you have not converted the image into numpy array but directly expanding the dimension, try to use the below lines of code -

---

```
 ret, frame = cap.read()
 image = np.asarray(frame)
 image_np = np.array(image)
```

---